# Which is a good way to send robot states between different ROS nodes?

Tags: ros, robotics

I am implementing a robotic system based on ROS. I have different nodes which send data multiple times per second. However, I don't need that. I want to send the robot state only when it is at a new location. What technique of ROS do you suggest to use?

Comment: Won't a topic accumulate a lot of information I don't need? Like past states?

Comment: The subscriber will only maintain up to however many messages you define the buffer to be. If this is some global state information, like a robot's position in the world, you might just make the subscriber callback save the latest incoming value in some variable. If you only use them infrequently, you can use `rospy.wait_for_message()` to grab one message.

Answer (score 4):

Dependent on your requirements, you can either use the [ROS Services](http://wiki.ros.org/Services) or the [Parameter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server).

> **ROS Service:** The publish / subscribe model is a very flexible
>   communication paradigm, but its many-to-many one-way transport is not
>   appropriate for RPC request / reply interactions, which are often
>   required in a distributed system. Request / reply is done via a
>   **Service**, which is defined by a pair of messages: one for the request
>   and one for the reply.
>
> **Parameter Server:** A parameter server is a shared, multi-variate dictionary that is accessible via network APIs. Nodes use this server
>   to store and retrieve parameters at runtime. As it is **not designed for**
>   **high-performance**, it is best used for static, non-binary data such as
>   configuration parameters.